# Redirect HTTPS With No Cert In Place

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, redirect, https

1. https:/ /SSLSite.com
2. http:/ /NoSSLSite.com

I need https:/ /NoSSLSite.com to redirect to https:/ /SSLSite.com .  Is this possible?  IIS webserver

Back story - We made some major changes recently.  But one dept sent paperwork to customer with old site URLS.  Those URLs no longer exist and the cert is off the server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your https:// site *needs* a certificate.  The SSL negotiation happens before any HTTP exchange takes place.  In order to redirect the client you need the browser to successfully establish an SSL connection.

You could use a self-signed certificate, although this will generate errors messages in the browser.  You could buy a 1-year SSL certificate which is only a few hundred dollars.

Comment: A few hundred?  If this is just a temporary thing to mask a URL typeo you might as well go with a cheap cert from Godaddy or someone for $50-80.

Comment: Whatever.  The point is that in any case it's cheap vs. confused customers and/or lost business.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing.  I think the cert was $120 or so.  Would upvote, but I dont have enough rep.  Am mainly a lurker.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I basic HTTP redirect in IIS7 should be able to handle that, unless I'm missing something.

Here's some more basic information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Dubyaohohdee, so is this a question about how to perform the redirect, or how to purchase an SSL certificate? Based on what I'm reading, it looks like you're basically looking to just do the redirect to avoid the hassle of having to notify the customer of the proper URL. Let me know if I'm mistaken, or if your question has been answered. Thanks.

Comment: That is correct.  Redirect w/o notifying of correct url.